# Entity Framework core: sum of sum doesn't work

Tags: entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to use this query using EF core:

```
entity.OrderBy(e => e.FieldOne.Sum(fo => fo.NestedField.Sum(nf => nf.SecondNestedField)));
```

Error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery. Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Is it possible to rewrite it EF core way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's sound not possible to call a complex expression in `Sum`. But you can flat the list and do a simple `Sum` like :

```cs
entity.OrderBy(e.FieldOne.SelectMany(fo => fo.NestedField).Sum(nf => nf.SecondNestedField));
```